# Way to launch and/or control Mac programs?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mechanize

Is there way to programmatically launch Mac programs at different times, or better yet, once an app has been started by you, the scheduler/timer/controller can send the app commands at different times?

Something like the Ruby and Perl Mechanize library (combined with Nokogiri), allowing a script to log in to and navigate a web site.

Even using apple script would be interesting. But I need to send a command to the app at different times.

Comment: I think "`cron`" still exists in some form under MacOS; why not combine Applescript (to launch & open your app) with a crontab?

Comment: Right. Cron would suffice to launch the controlling script. But AppleScript is what my script should use to interact with / control Apple desktop apps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)** to run  the `osascript` command, which allows you to execute AppleScripts.

Example of the `osascript` usage:

```
$ # Using an AppleScript file
$ osascript QuitFinder.scpt
$
$ # Using a command
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to quit'
```

You can run `man osascript` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, and it costs $20, but if AppleScript doesn't suffice and you need to send fake mouse gestures/keystrokes to an app, [Keymando](http://keymando.com/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

How about Applescript + iCal

http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011/01/12/how-to-use-ical-to-run-an-applescript/